# Opensource self-hosted knowledgebase application

Tags: linux, open-source, self-hosted, knowledge-base

I'm after an application that I can use to store information.

- It must be opensource
- preferably written in PHP for easy manipulation
- for a single user, so ACLs are unneccessary
- preferably use Markdown
- preferably database-less, storing the content as files
- allow the creation of books/guides (grouped pages) as well as single pages
- allow the content to be searchable
- preferably live preview
- extensionable with a plugin system
- installable on a Linux server
- preferably without excessive user login / profile functionality as this isn't needed

Comment: As a single user, does it actually need to be server based, or would a standalone software like OpenOffice do the trick for you?

Comment: @Marcel yes, I want to be able to access it from various devices.

Comment: [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tedegraph.tedegraph) is not exactly what you're looking for, but could be a good aditional tool.

Answer (score 2):

[DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/) sounds like a good candidate:

- opensource
- written in PHP
- intended for private use, small to medium companies
- Markdown support as plugin
- no database required
- searchable
- preview available
- extensionable with a plugin system
- installable on a Linux server
- creation of books/guides (grouped pages) as well as single pages - *not sure*

Maybe worth a look. Also, if you are curious, check out [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) to have a look at the available wikis.

Comment: I don't like WikiMatrix, the database is poor, the best wikifarms are not included.